# Add array to array of keys in web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

My web.config looks like this

```
<add key="StudentName1" value="English, Maths, French" />
<add key="StudentName2" value="English" />
<add key="StudentName3" value="English, French" />
```

The number of students can be increased or decreased. How would I read this in c#? Its a array inside an array

Comment: StudentName will not be an array. It's a key-value pair.

Comment: But in code how to loop around the keys? How will I know the value of key in 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentName1"]

Comment: @user2837961: I am not sure `web.config` is a good place to store these kind of data?

Comment: You probably should use some other approach to store your students. You could loop with an index. ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentName" + index]; I would strongly discourage this method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store an array/list of students you should look into serializing. You could create some models like this:

```
public class Student 
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class MySettings
{
    public List<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

You can add your Students to the Students list within MySettings. Each student could have 0 or more courses (rather than doing a comma separated variant).

Then serialize the MySettings and store it on the filesystem.

```
public static class MySerializer
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(string path, string fileName)
        {
            string fullPath = path + fileName;
            if (!path.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                fullPath = path + "/" + fileName;
            }

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fullPath))
            {
                T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(fileReader);

                return instance;
            } 
        }

        public static void ToFile<T>(T currentObject, string path, string fileName)
        {
            string fullPath = path + fileName;
            if (!path.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                fullPath = path + "/" + fileName;
            }

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullPath))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(file, currentObject);
            }
        }

}
```

You can then use the solution like this:

```
var student = new Student();
student.Name = "Student1";
student.Courses = new List<Course>() { new Course() { Name = "English" } };

MySettings settings = new MySettings();
settings.Students = new List<Student>();
settings.Students.Add(student);

MySerializer.ToFile<MySettings>(settings, @"c:\temp", "settings.xml"); // serialize to c:\temp\settings.xml

settings = MySerializer.ToObject<MySettings>(@"c:\temp", "settings.xml"); // deserialize to c:\temp\settings.xml
```